# does the Linux distribution matters for noarch packages?

Tags: python, rpm, httplib2, rhel5

I need httplib2 v0.7 RPM for RHEL 5.7, but can't find one. So,

1. do you by chance know where can I get some?
2. I see such RPMs but for other distros (e.g. Mandrake). Since it is python-only lib (noarch) does the distro matters? Can I get any and use it?

Python 2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does matter.

noarch marks a package as usable for every CPU architecture, usually when there are no compiled binaries in it.

But the distribution matters in general. A noarch package from another distro may or may not work. It depends e.g. on package names, directories where to put the stuff, ...

A package only works safely if the distribution and the distribution version matches.